# How do VoIP connections differ with and without gatekeeper?

Tags: voip

difference between voip with and without gatekeeper?

Answer (score 0):

A gatekeeper can be used when the VoIP endpoints (eg. phones) use the H.323 protocol.

When a gatekeeper is used the, the endpoints must register with the gatekeeper and will ask the gatekeeper permission for each call. This allowes the endpoints to dial by phone numbers and names rather than IPs. In addition the gatekeeper can provide services such as accounting and firewall traversal.

See the [GNU Gatekeeper FAQ](http://www.gnugk.org/h323-faq.html) for more details.

Comment: is 'gatekeeper' referring to the service provider for the VoIP connection?

Comment: If you are using a service provider for H.323, he will most likely be running your gatekeeper, but you can also install one locally.